# Dashboard layout with fixed sidebar and top bar in css

Tags: css, css-position

I am creating a dashboard app which has a Side Bar where users can perform some actions and a Top Bar where they can log in log out etc. I am trying to achieve the following 2 layouts:

Both the Side Bar and the Top Bar should be fixed vs the content should be scrollable

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML is the same:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="topbar">Topbar</div>
  <div class="scrollable-content"><h1>Scrollable content</h1>
    Lots of text
  </div>
</div>
```

The css for the LHS (where the side bar extends to the top of the screen):

```
body {
  margin:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color:darkblue;
}
.container {
  --topbar-height:50px;
  --sidebar-width:100px;
  color:white;
}
.sidebar {
  position:fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: var(--sidebar-width);
  height:100vh;
  background-color: darkgreen;
}
.topbar {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height: var(--topbar-height);
  margin-left: var(--sidebar-width);
  background-color:magenta;
}
.scrollable-content {
  margin-top: var(--topbar-height);
  margin-left: var(--sidebar-width);
  background-color:darkblue;
}
```

For the 2nd solution (the topbar extends the full width)

```
body {
  margin:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color:darkblue;
}
.container {
  --topbar-height:50px;
  --sidebar-width:100px;
  color:white;
}
.sidebar {
  position:fixed;
  top: var(--topbar-height);
  width: var(--sidebar-width);
  height: calc(100vh - var(--topbar-height));
  background-color: darkgreen;
}
.topbar {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height: var(--topbar-height);
  background-color:magenta;
}
.scrollable-content {
  margin-top: var(--topbar-height);
  margin-left: var(--sidebar-width);
  background-color:darkblue;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Just so you know, if you adjust padding etc to the .scrollable-content div it can break the calcs so put your content inside a div with a margin set.

Comment: Is there a way to set the topbar width as `100% - (--sidebar-width)`

Comment: That would also work by setting width: calc(100% - var(--sidebar-width)); as the top bar will try to fit as much space as it can. As it's position: fixed you can also use right: 0;

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS `position` property to achieve this.

```css
#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100px;
}

/* Width for sidebar and height for topbar will be relative to the content you can change */
#topbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 100px;
  height: fit-content;
}

/* Adjust padding to avoid content being covered by the top and sidebar */
body {
  padding: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Why did you use padding to avoid the content being covered? Are there other options e.g. margin?

Comment: Yes, I did use padding to avoid the content being covered. Margin will work as well.